# Error: ../arch/arm64/boot/dts/sprd/ums512-w27v1.dts:1044.1-15 Label or path modem_dbg_log not found

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation

```
Error: ../arch/arm64/boot/dts/sprd/ums512-w27v1.dts:1044.1-15 Label or path modem_dbg_log not found

FATAL ERROR: Syntax error parsing input tree
```

Hi I'm trying to compile realme c21y kernel,an arm64 android device with unisoc t610 soc when I tried to compile this kernel I got this error.
I used this script for compiling this kernel

```
#!/system/bin/sh

if [[ -d "out" ]]

then

  cd out && make clean && make distclean && make mrproper && cd ..

else

  mkdir -p out

fi

make O=out ARCH=arm64 sprd_sharkl5Pro_defconfig

export CLANG_PATH=/root/clang-6573524/clang-11/bin

make       O=out \

           ARCH=arm64 \

           CC=clang \

           CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- \

           CROSS_COMPILE_ARM32=arm-linux-gnueabi- \

           AR=llvm-ar \

           NM=llvm-nm \

           OBJCOPY=llvm-objcopy \
           OBJDUMP=llvm-objdump \
           STRIP=llvm-strip \
           -j8
```

```
  CC      net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_dup_ipv4.o

  CC      drivers/gpu/drm/sprd/gsp/gsp_interface/gsp_interface_roc1.o

  CC      net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_netbios_ns.o

  CC      lib/hexdump.o

  DTC     arch/arm64/boot/dts/sprd/sc9863a-w12v1.dtb

  DTC     arch/arm64/boot/dts/sprd/ums512-w27v1.dtb

  AR      drivers/gpu/drm/sprd/dsi/core/built-in.o

  AR      drivers/gpu/drm/sprd/dsi/built-in.o

  CC      lib/kstrtox.o

  CC      lib/pci_iomap.o

Error: ../arch/arm64/boot/dts/sprd/ums512-w27v1.dts:1044.1-15 Label or path modem_dbg_log not found

FATAL ERROR: Syntax error parsing input tree

make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.lib:317: arch/arm64/boot/dts/sprd/ums512-w27v1.dtb] Error 1

make[2]: *** [../scripts/Makefile.build:676: arch/arm64/boot/dts/sprd] Error 2

make[1]: *** [arch/arm64/Makefile:201: dtbs] Error 2

make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

  CC      drivers/gpu/drm/sprd/gsp/gsp_interface/gsp_interface_sharkl5pro.o

  CC      net/nfc/llcp_commands.o

  CC      net/nfc/llcp_sock.o

  CC      drivers/gpu/drm/sprd/oplus_engine/oplus_display_private_api.o

  CC      net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_pptp.o

  CC      lib/iomap_copy.o

  AR      net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_conntrack_ipv4.o

  AR      net/
```

After some time I got this error.

Someone please explain me what is this error and what is the solution for it.
Thank you...